# Get form data from formData() object in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How to get data submitted via `formData()` object in Ajax and jQuery to PHP file.

```
 //jQuery sample code
    if((unerr = "")){
            $.ajax({
                method: "post",
                url : "ajax.php",
                data: new FormData(this),
                processData: false,
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false
            })
            .done(function(data){
                if(data == "error"){
                  $("#msg").html("<p class='text-danger'>An error occured, please try again</p>").fadeIn("slow");
              }
            });
        }
//php file

    <?php
//Database connection
include_once('includes/db_connect.php');
if($_POST){
  $username = $_POST['un'];
//insert values
$insert_values=$con->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username) VALUES(?)");
$insert_values->execute(array($username));
$affected_rows = insert_values->rowCount();
if($insert_values->execute()){
    echo "great";
}else{
    echo "error";
}  
}

?>
```

I get no response while submitting the form, I don't know what could be wrong.

Comment: `new FormData(this)` ? `this` refer to what?

Comment: $("#signup_form").submit(function(e){

Comment: it refers to the sign up form from which to get data

Comment: use `var_dump($_POST);` in your `php` code, see the result

Comment: Try `new FormData($('form')[0])`

Answer (score 1):

Try using below ajax code check result of $_POST response array.

```
$("#signup_form").submit(function(e){
    $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: new FormData($("#signup_form")[0]),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(done){
              console.log(done)
            },
            error: function(error){
              console.log(error);
            }
        });
});
```